# Using numpy to solve a linear system with one uknown?

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a really simple problem programatically.

I have a single variable t that must satisfy 2 equations simultaneously as follows:

```
x_v*t = (x_1 - x_2)
y_v*t = (y_1 - y_2)
```

My first reaction is to just solve it by dividing the right side by the coefficient in the left, however that coefficient is not guaranteed to be non 0.

Thus we can always use the RREF algorithm and represent the system as:

```
 a | b
 c | d
```

where a = x_v, b = (x_1 - x_2), c = y_v, d = (y_1 - y_2)

After finding the RREF we could have:

- The 0 matrix (system is solvable)
- First row has a leading one and the second row is 0's (system is sovable)
- Either row has a leading 0 and a non zero trailing number (system is not solvable)

Although I could try to code the above myself, I wanted to use a library instead where I can just setup the system and ask an api whether a solution exists or not, so I used numpy.

Currently however I can't even set a system where the non-extended matrix is not square.

Is this achievable?

Comment: You can just pick one of your equations and use [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) or pick both and use [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) and check the residuals.

Comment: Is your question voluntarily restricted to linear cases ?

Comment: @Kanak The problem I am trying to solve is guaranteed to be a linear system, yes

Comment: Numpy yields numerical solutions -- if you are interested in symbolic solutions, take a look at Sympy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable. You can use the function [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) of the [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) library. An example

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so

def f(t, x_v, x_1, x_2, y_v, y_1, y_2):
    return np.sum(np.abs([
        x_v*t - (x_1 - x_2),
        y_v*t - (y_1 - y_2),
    ]))
```

and then you would do

```
sol_object = so.fsolve(
    func = f,                  # the function that returns the (scalar) 0 you want. 
    x0   = 1,                  # The starting estimate
    args = (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), # Other arguments of f, i.e. x_v, x_1, x_2, y_v, y_1, y_2 
    full_output = True
)
sol        = sol_object[0]
message    = sol_object[-1]

print(sol)
print(message)
```

***Output***

```
[-1.]
The solution converged.
```

---

As mentioned in comment by jdhesa, this could have been done using linear-in-parameter solving methods. The one I use above *a priori* works with any kind of transformation.

Comment: Being a linear system you can just use the solvers in [`numpy.linalg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html).

Comment: @jdhesa Sure. But for the sake of generality, I wanted to provide the OP with the most robust approach. But you are right, it makes sens to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to just perform the division.
If both "sides" are zero then the result will be NaN (0/0).
If the rhs i.e. (x_1 - x_2) is nonzero the result will be inf.

```
# c1 is np.array([x_1, y_1, z_1, ...])
# c2 is np.array([x_2, y_2, z_2, ...])
c = c1 - c2
# Use this to supress numpy warnings
with np.warnings.catch_warnings():
    np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 'invalid value encountered in true_divide')
    np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore','divide by zero encountered in true_divide')
    t = c / v
non_nan_t = t[~np.isnan(t)]
if np.isinf(t).any():
    print('unsolvable because rhs is nonzero but v is zero')

elif not np.allclose(non_nan_t, non_nan_t[0]):
    print('no solution because equations disagree')
else:
    print('solution:', non_nan_t[0])
```